# CacheBust in dojoConfig breaks paths

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have the same problem [someone reported a year ago on ESRI forum](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/154509): the query string appears before the file name, just after the last slash, like this:

```
http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/images/symbol/sfs/?1430314495556diagonalcross.png
```

For me it's the same, except for my `cacheBust` doesn't break `.png` images, but `manifest.json` files (but not `config.json`). Seems that somewhere is a switch of supported extensions/filenames with "add query string after the last slash" rule as the default. Adding a query string after the filename didn't help - dojo added another querystring where it shouldn't be.

If this is really caused by an unsensible whitelist, I need to find and change it. I checked the Web AppBuilder (version 1.4) and found no mention of the `cacheBust`. Another possible culprit is the ArcGIS JavaScript API (3.15 in my case) - it contains a reference for `cacheBust` on line 11 in its obfuscated [`init.js`](http://js.arcgis.com/3.15/init.js), but I didn't manage to track the place where the query string is placed to the URL. The bug being in Dojo itself (1.10) seems unlikely, but it still seems possible.

Is there any solution available? Using downloaded code for the API is OK. If not, can anyone help me locate the right place in the code, or refute that the problem is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the API, looked at it a little and realized that there's no restrictive whitelist. The querystring is just assigned too early, to a base URL to which the filenames are added later. So the solution would be to find where are the filenames added and make this process querystring-aware.

So I found where the manifest.json was assigned (in the Web AppBuilder, file `WidgetManager`) and changed it to handle the querystring:

```
if (widgetJson.folderUrl.indexOf("?") > -1) {
    url = widgetJson.folderUrl.substr(0, widgetJson.folderUrl.indexOf("?")) + 'manifest.json' + widgetJson.folderUrl.substr(widgetJson.folderUrl.indexOf("?"));
} else {
    //this is how it looked before
    url = widgetJson.folderUrl + 'manifest.json';
}
```

The code might be slightly more elegant, but it works. There were some other files garbled by the `cacheBust`, but this algorithm worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did some checking into the code as mentioned in another answer:

```
if (widgetJson.folderUrl.indexOf("?") > -1) {
    url = widgetJson.folderUrl.substr(0, widgetJson.folderUrl.indexOf("?")) + 'manifest.json' + widgetJson.folderUrl.substr(widgetJson.folderUrl.indexOf("?"));
} else {
    //this is how it looked before
    url = widgetJson.folderUrl + 'manifest.json';
}
```

I do not recommend that approach.  I'm using v2.3.

The code to determine the url to use differs in the 3d and 2d portions of the product.  This code only fixes the url problem with manifest.json files.  It does not fix the same problem with the icon files (or possibly other file types).

In addition, when you change the web appbuilder application code, it gets copied into each new application that you create.   Conversely, if you have already created an application, you will have to make the change again, once per existing application.   Each new file type issue that crops up will cause one more fix per web appbuilder product installation and per application built with it.  Each new upgrade from Esri might require the exact same changes to be made all over again.

I would recommend not to set CacheBust to true until Esri fixes the underlying code problem rather than attempting to patch this.